# How can I convert a Qualcomm firehose file from bin to elf, in order to load it in QFIL?

Tags: android, windows, elf, qualcomm

I have a Oneplus 7T HD1907 stuck in recovery mode.

I wanna use this [guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-dump-and-write-back-the-storage-on-most-of-qualcomm-devices.3949588/) to copy the userdata partition to my computer, before I proceed with factory resetting the phone.

I used [Firehose Finder](https://github.com/hoplik/Firehose-Finder) to get the correct firehose file for my device, but it's in bin file format. However QFIL only accepts elf or mbn files. How can i convert this firehose file safely on Windows?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project that uses the Qualcomm protocol that uses the firehose in a .bin format.

github.com/bkerler/edl

I have used it to pull backup images, and restore them to my Oneplus 8

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Qualcomm Firehose loaders are actually ELF files (either 32 or 64 bit). They usually have an .elf or .bin extension. If your EDL client is so picky you can just rename the loader.